# Google Web Detection search for local results

Tags: google-custom-search

As you know, we can search an image by using Google Image search. The result will give priority to displaying websites near you. For example I am in Vietnam, it will display Vietnamese websites.

Now I am using Google Web Detection to search all websites contain an image. By following this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-web. The results is good but it show many website from others country. How can I focus result to Vietnamese only?